# code about finding subsequences in a list returning none

Tags: python

This code is supposed to return the longest subsequence of string that exists in the list 'words' (Word W is a subsequence of S if some number of characters, possibly zero, can be deleted from S to form W, without reordering the remaining characters). But it is returning None for any input values and I cannot understand why. Any advice?

````
string = input()
words = (input()).split()
def longest_subsequence (string, words):
  words = list(words)
  max_length = 0
  max_sub = ""
  for i in range(len(words)):
    ind = i
    isSubsequence = True
    for j in words[i]:
      if j == string[ind]:
        ind +=1
      else:
        isSubsequence = False
        break
    if isSubsequence and max_length < len(words[i].split()):
      max_length = len(words[i].split())
      max_sub = words[i]
  return max_sub
print (longest_subsequence(string, words))```
````

Comment: How did you determine that it returns `None`?

Comment: your second line is suspect, as you are looking for input again, maybe try `words=string.split()`

Comment: @jeremy_rutman I think that's fine - `words` is supposed to be a list of substrings to look for. If you took `words = string.split()`, the longest occurring substring of `string` in `words` would simply be the longest element of `words`

Comment: yes i think you're right.  BTW @whatever, did your substrings have to be contiguous or not? From your definition it seems not in which case I don't think your code will work.

Comment: It does not return `None` for all input values. I checked and it returns the subsequence only if it is the first word of list `words`

Answer (score 0):

depending on what exactly you are looking for this may help:

```
def substrings(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        for j in range(len(word),0,-1):
            new_word = word[i:j]
            if new_word:
                yield new_word

def subseqs(string,sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    sbstrs = [s for s in substrings(string)]
    for word in words:
        subseqs = [s for s in sbstrs if s in word]
        print(subseqs)
```

which gets you :

```
print(subseqs('ban','my banana has been banned'))
[]
['ban', 'ba', 'b', 'an', 'a', 'n']
['a']
['b', 'n']
['ban', 'ba', 'b', 'an', 'a', 'n']
```

It wasn't clear to me if you need the substring to be contained in all the words, this just finds all substrings in each word, from which the longest can be found - depending on whether you want a single answer or all equal-length substrings if there are more than one . 
If you just want one of the possibly many longest substrings then `max(subseqs, key=len)` may come in handy. Also it wasnt clear if the substrings have to be contiguous (as this returns) or not (as may be the case from your description) .

Answer (score 0):

Here is where you go wrong:

```
if isSubsequence and max_length < len(words[i].split()):
      max_length = len(words[i].split())
      max_sub = words[i]
```

This conditional statement executes only once, because initially `isSubsequence` is True and `max_length` is zero. So `max_sub` gets returned only if subsequence is the first word in list of words. For other iterations `max_length < len(words[i].split())` never holds true as `len(words[i].split())` always returns 1. You should try this instead:

```
string = input()
words = (input()).split()
def longest_subsequence (string, words):
  words = list(words)
  max_length = 0
  max_sub = ""
  for i in range(len(words)):
    ind = 0
    isSubsequence = True
    for j in words[i]:
      if j == string[ind]:
        ind +=1
      else:
        isSubsequence = False
        break
    if isSubsequence and len(words[i]) > max_length:
      max_length = len(words[i].split())
      max_sub = words[i]
  return max_sub
print (longest_subsequence(string, words))
```